# BNF for a hexadecimal number

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf

As a homework assignment I have to write a BNF definition for a hexadecimal number `<hex>`.

This is to be done using `<digit>` and `<letter>`, both of which are defined as follows:

```
<digit> ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
<letter> ::= A | B | C | D | E | F
```

The textbook answer is given as:

```
<hex> ::= <digit> | <letter> | <hex> <digit> | <hex> <letter>
```

I agree that this is a correct answer, but I would like to ask if it is also correct to give the answer as the following:

```
<hex> ::= <digit> | <letter> | <hex> <hex>
```

Comment: it produces the same language, but it is ambiguous.

Comment: `<hex> <hex>` will never know whether to reduce to `<letter> <hex>` or `<hex> <digit>` in the case of something like `A20C64`. This is what makes it ambiguous.

Comment: Note to self: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22463/208787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, just look at the parse trees produced by [textbook grammar](https://gist.github.com/rns/85c6d18fb62065ae1617#file-unambiguous) vs. 
[suggested grammar](https://gist.github.com/rns/85c6d18fb62065ae1617#file-ambiguous) ([code](https://gist.github.com/rns/85c6d18fb62065ae1617#file-q28192282-pl)). Note: parse trees represent derivations.

Comment: some parser generators can resolve ambigouities defining precedence or associativity relations. whether the second grammar is correct or not depends on the context where it will be used.

Comment: @1010 -- sure, but in this case the parse tree produced by the textbook grammar is not among the parse trees produced by the second grammar. Also, language equality -- "Given two CFGs, do they generate the same language?" is undecidable -- http://goo.gl/rJeEfS.

Comment: different grammars will have different parse trees.

Comment: the undecidability of the equivalence of two CFGs stands for the general case of any two grammars. there will be particular cases where it can be demonstrated that two grammars generate the same language.

Comment: There will, yes, but I can't see the way to do it in this case, c.f. Chrono Kitsune's comment above. I'd like to be proven wrong though.

Comment: it can be proven by induction on the length of the string that any string of hex digits can be derivated with these grammars. on the other side any string derivated from these grammars will be a string of hex digits,  so their language is the set of hex numbers.